# html features modules isn't loading angular 6

Tags: angular

Excuse my english, I am following angular docs. I am creating two features modules, 
the second is working, but the first isn't. My code is here:

app-routing.module

```
    { path: 'customer', loadChildren: './customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'},  
  { path: 'orders', loadChildren: './orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'},
```

orders-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OrdersListComponent } from './orders-list/orders-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: OrdersListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrdersRoutingModule { }
```

which it's working fine.

customers-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CustomersListComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomersRoutingModule { }
```

which isn't loading, it goes to its path but isn't loading the component

customers-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers-list',
  template: `<p>customers-list works!!</p>`,
  styleUrls: ['./customers-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    console.log('customers component launched');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h2>{{ title }}</h2>
<ul>
  <li><button routerLink="/customer">Customers</button></li>
  <li><button routerLink="/orders">Orders</button></li>
  <li><button routerLink="">Home</button></li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div>
  <app-publi [ads]="ads"></app-publi>
</div>
```

I have not got any error console, so I cannot find out what happen?

Anybody can help me? thanks.

Comment: Nice first question :) Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) showcasing your problem?

Comment: I created a project in stackblitz and it is working fine. So I return to my project. The problem was that my editor was not saving my changes in that file. Thanks aloisdg, your advice was important